# tikz pgf - create bubble plot without using file content

Tags: pgfplots

I have a working example of a bubble plot using filecontents, where the last column defines the size of the bubbles.

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the same plot without using filecontents? Is there a way for latex to read the third value when you add them as coordinates?

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left =2cm, top = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font

\begin{filecontents*}{temp1.dat}
x  Price Val
A  180  14.42
B  869  171.7
C  448  144.342
D  821  20.5
E  790 80.9
F  219  42.5
G  582  61.65
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=4.5in,
          height=3.5in,
          xtick=data,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
          scale only axis,
          colorbar,
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east,align=center},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          mark=*,
          point meta=explicit,
          visualization depends on = {0.2*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize},
      ] table [x={x},y={Price},meta index=2] {temp1.dat};      
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Most likely this will not be possible, because of a bug in PGFPlots, which is already reported in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/). It will be fixed (for numerical values) with the release of v1.16.

Answer (score 2):

You can just dump the content of the file in the `\addplot`. I.e. `\addplot table[..] {<content of file>};`

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left =2cm, top = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % loads pgfplots, which loads tikz, which loads graphicx
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=4.5in,
          height=3.5in,
          xtick=data,
          symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
          scale only axis,
          colorbar,
          xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east,align=center},
       ]
      \addplot[%
          scatter=true,
          only marks,
          mark=*,
          point meta=explicit,
          visualization depends on = {0.2*\thisrow{Val} \as \perpointmarksize},
          scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\perpointmarksize},
      ] table [x={x},y={Price},meta index=2] {
x  Price Val
A  180  14.42
B  869  171.7
C  448  144.342
D  821  20.5
E  790 80.9
F  219  42.5
G  582  61.65
};      
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```